# Opening ALSA Microphone in two programs?

Tags: audio, alsa, recording

I'm using a raspberry pi to capture some audio, but I only want it to do it when the noise level goes above a certain level, and then the device will record until two seconds after it falls below that level again.

I have a python program, audioserver.py which starts and stops another program, arecord, from recording from the microphone input.

However, it appears that one program cannot have the audio device open while the other already does - is there a way I could overcome this problem and open my ALSA Microphone device more than once?

Comment: I guess something like JACK (http://jackaudio.org) could do that,  but that's not easy to set up , I believe.

Answer (score 0):

The dsnoop plugin allows multiple clients to record from the same device.

In theory, the `default` device should already use this plugin.
If not, record from the `dsnoop` device.